# Using Minitest to Test File Write

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

Is there a way to use minitest to mock/stub file reads and writes (text files) without actually having them existing?

the actual code is something like

```
def write_to_file(filename)

 f = File.open(filename,"w")

 f.puts "hello world"

 f.close
end
```

I really don't know how to try something since I couldn't find any examples for mocking File IO, only comparing variables

Comment: Mocking is covered in [the documentation](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). What have you tried, why didn't it work? [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were going to do what you're suggesting, I would stub `File.open` to return a mock like:

```
def test_something_that_reads_a_file
  file_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
  file_mock.expect(:readline, "It was the best of times...")
  File.stub(:open, file_mock) do
    # your test logic here
  end
  file_mock.verify
end
```

You still have the problem of returning `EOF` at some point, but whether that's an issue for you depends on context that I don't have given what you've written.

But there are a couple of reasons why I would probably never approach the problem like this.

1. Don't mock what you don't own.  Yes, the semantics of `File#readline` are probably not going to change tomorrow, but making assumptions about an interface that's outside your control is a bad practice.
2. To me, this reads like a non-public method.  If I'm right about that, then I wouldn't test it at all.  Private methods are implementation details that don't need their own tests.  If you're dead set on not doing any I/O here, I'd rather stub the result of the method rather than what I've done above.

The approach I would take would be to include a small test file and actually read from it.  Your tests will be easier to understand as a result.

Comment: thanks, I think it will just do what you said and compare tests text files instead of mocking

Comment: If you like it, put a check on it.  :)